# bash array declaration or slice does not work with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I have this easiest bash script

```
arr=('one' 'two' 'three' 'four');
echo "${arr[@]:2}" > test.txt
```

(in fact i want to used ${@:2})

If I run this script in command line with ./my_script.sh, it work as expected. But when I try to use a java ProcessBuilder, the test.txt file is never created. (in fact the bash script stop the execution at the slice).

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./my_script.sh");
    pb.start();
```

i tried with a lot of other command in my bash script and everything work fine with processBuilder, all exept the "${@:2}".

for exemple this script work fine and create test.txt in my project directory

```
echo "test" > test.txt
```

Someone know why?

Comment: Have you tried `/bin/sh ./compile_evo.sh` ? Or maybe you are in a wrong Directory?

Comment: when I run `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "./my_script.sh");` it still work with a simple echo but still not work with the first script.

Comment: Make sure your script starts with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang

Comment: Oh thanks @glenn-jackman, I missed this line...  It fix the problem.